# Batch folder create and name it

Tags: batch-file, directory

I am trying to create a bat file to create folder. This is the current version of the script I need to enhance.

```
md Project
md Project\Work
md Project\Deliver
```

Here is my question:

When I run the bat, it currently creates a folder as "Project".
Instead, the script should ask me the name of the folder that needs to be created. My naming convention is as: YYAADD_projectname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the following bat script. Let me know if it's not working.

Anyway I don't know what you meat by YYAADD_. 
If it is YYMMDD_ as for YEAR MONTH and DATE you will have to change the script accordingly.

```
@echo off
set /p dname= Enter Directory Name?
md YYAADD_%dname%
md YYAADD_%dname%
md YYAADD_%dname%\Work
md YYAADD_%dname%\Deliver
```

Following is with the YYMMDD part as you have mentioned in the comment later.

```
@echo off
FOR /F "TOKENS=1* DELIMS= " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET CDATE=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=2,3 DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('echo %CDATE%') DO SET yy=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 eol=/ DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET mm=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 DELIMS=/ eol=/" %%A IN ('echo %CDATE%') DO SET dd=%%B
SET SUBSTRING=%yy:~2,2%
SET date=%SUBSTRING%%mm%%dd%

set /p dname= Enter Directory Name?
md %date%_%dname%
md %date%_%dname%
md %date%_%dname%\Work
md %date%_%dname%\Deliver
```

Comment: Yes you are right. It works perfectly. YY is last two digit of year, AA is month (sorry it should be MM) and DD is day.

Comment: @Just-a-user , checkout the second script, it is what you want right ?

Comment: I know this is and old question but what if you want spaces in the folder name? e.g. _My documents_

Comment: @Arete yes in that case you have to provide folder name within inverted commas. Eg: "My Documents"

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
@echo off

set /p id="Enter Project Name: " %=%
md "Project"\%id%
```